# Is there a global_variable_set for ruby?

Tags: ruby

If one was to make a Tk GUI in Ruby and make multiple checkboxes with different global variable names. What would be the most efficient way of doing so?

I found the `instance_variable_set`, but as this wouldn't fit my scenario.

I wondered if there was such a thing as something like a `global_variable_set`.

Eg.

```
    info = [orange,apple,banana,grape,watermelon]
    $var = TkVariable.New
    info.each_with_index {|inf,index|
      TkCheckButton.new(frame1) do 
        text "#{inf}"
        onvalue "#{inf}"
        variable global_variable_set("$var#{index}", inf)
      end
    end
```

Comment: [`Module#const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set)?

Comment: Why do your want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve that you couldn't solve with, say, a Hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wondered if there was such [a] thing as something like a `global_variable_set`.

Yes—it's [`Module#module_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.5/Module.html#method-i-module_eval). Here's your code, reworked to use it:

```rb
require 'tk'

$root = TkRoot.new
$frame1 = Tk::Tile::Frame.new $root

check_buttons = []
info = %w[orange apple banana grape watermelon]
info.each_with_index do |inf,index|
  global_name = "$var#{index}"

  cb = Tk::Tile::CheckButton.new $frame1
  cb.text "#{inf}"
  cb.onvalue "#{inf}"

  create_global = "#{global_name} = TkVariable.new ''"
  Module.module_eval create_global

  assign_value = "#{global_name}.value = '#{inf}'"
  Module.module_eval assign_value

  connect_variable = "cb.variable #{global_name}"
  Module.module_eval connect_variable

  check_buttons.push cb
end

p Kernel.global_variables.select {|e| e.id2name.start_with? '$var'}
p info.length.times.map {|i| Module.module_eval "$var#{i}.value"}
p check_buttons.map {|e| (e.cget :variable).value}

Tk.mainloop
```

The program produces the following output:

```
[:$var0, :$var1, :$var2, :$var3, :$var4]
["orange", "apple", "banana", "grape", "watermelon"]
["orange", "apple", "banana", "grape", "watermelon"]
```

Or you can use the more general method, [Kernel#eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.5/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) instead.

So if dynamic creation of global variables really is what you want to do, it's available.

Checkbutton method `cget`'s Tcl documentation can be seen [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/checkbutton.htm#M8).

I tested this on Windows 7 using Ruby 2.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't test this. But I suppose this would be of some help to you:

As per this [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/quality_extensions/1.3.1/Kernel%3Aglobal_variable_set)

There seems a method defined in `lib/quality_extensions/global_variable_set.rb`

*Please note that this documentation is for the [quality extensions gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/quality_extensions) which is not built-in* (Thanks [Jordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan))

> ```
> global_variable_set(var, value, options = {}) ⇒ Object
> ```
>
> Sets the global variable var, which can either be a symbol or an
>   actual global variable (use `:match_object`).
>
> ```
> global_variable_set(:$a, 'new')
> global_variable_set($a, 'new', :match_object => true)
> global_variable_set(:$a, "StringIO.new", :eval_string => true)
> ```

Hope this helps?

Comment: The linked documentation is for the quality_extensions gem. It is not built in.